# Changing Color of Chart Shape Textbox (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Having trouble figuring out how to take the input of a `.Font.ColorIndex` and using it to change the font color of a chart's textbox shape.

`.Font.ColorIndex` returns 48

When I change the color of the text in a macro, it returns this:

```
        With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1 ' How to set this value from a font color? Can you?
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
```

Is this possible?

Comment: yea... msoThemeColorBackground1 is 14.

Comment: Right, but putting in a number where `msoThemeColorBackground1` is gives me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing different color types. ObjectThemeColor represents a different type of color than what you have as 48.

Looking at [Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorformat-object-excel) The available options are:

[image: Color types]

You probably want to convert your ColorIndex to RGB and then insert. You'll need a custom function, but not hard. Just paste this function somewhere into your Code module.

```
Function getRGB(C As Long, LetterTYPE As String) As Integer
        Dim R As Long
        Dim G As Long
        Dim B As Long

        R = C Mod 256
        G = C \ 256 Mod 256
        B = C \ 65536 Mod 256

        If UCase(LetterTYPE) = "R" Then
           getRGB = R
        ElseIf UCase(LetterTYPE) = "G" Then
            getRGB = G
        ElseIf UCase(LetterTYPE) = "B" Then
            getRGB = B
        End If
End Function
```

Then rewrite your original code to include newly created formula:

```
YourColor = 48
  With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(getRGB(YourColor , "R"), getRGB(YourColor , "G"), getRGB(YourColor , "B"))
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
```

Comment: My previous code had an error in the `ForeColor` line. I corrected it.